# How do I add a Modal to a complex Ionic app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app set up with a similar navigation style as this codepen:

http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/JdtuG

HTML:

```
    <title>Ionic Template</title>

    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.27/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.27/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- ALL VIEW STATES LOADED IN HERE -->
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

<script id="entry.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-nav-bar animation="nav-title-slide-ios7"
                 type="bar-positive"
                 back-button-type="button-icon"
                 back-button-icon="ion-ios7-arrow-back">
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-view title="{{navTitle}}" class="bubble-background">

        <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">

            <h1>Entry Page!</h1>

            <a class="button button-positive" ng-click="signIn()" ui-sref="main.home">Sign In</a>

        </ion-content>

    </ion-view>

</script>

<script id="tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view title="{{navTitle}}"  left-buttons="leftButtons">

        <ion-tabs tabs-type="tabs-icon-only">
            <ion-tab title="Tab 1" icon-on="ion-ios7-filing" icon-off="ion-ios7-filing-outline">
                <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
                    <h2>Tab 1 Content</h2>
                </ion-content>
            </ion-tab>

            <ion-tab title="Tab 2" icon-on="ion-ios7-filing" icon-off="ion-ios7-filing-outline">
                <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
                    <h2>Tab 2 Content</h2>
                </ion-content>
            </ion-tab>

            <ion-tab title="Tab 3" icon-on="ion-ios7-filing" icon-off="ion-ios7-filing-outline">
                <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
                    <h2>Tab 3 Content</h2>
                </ion-content>
            </ion-tab>
        </ion-tabs>


    </ion-view>
</script>

<script id="mainContainer.html" type="text/ng-template">

    <ion-side-menus>

        <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
            <ion-nav-bar type="bar-positive"
                         back-button-type="button-icon"
                         back-button-icon="ion-ios7-arrow-back"
                         animation="nav-title-slide-ios7"
                >

             </ion-nav-bar>
            <ion-nav-view name="main"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-pane>

        <ion-side-menu side="left">
            <header class="bar bar-header bar-assertive">
                <div class="title">Side Menu</div>
            </header>
            <ion-content has-header="true">
                <ul class="list">
                    <a ui-sref="entry" class="item">Back To Entry Page</a>
                    <a ui-sref="main.home" class="item" ng-click="toggleMenu()">Home</a>
                    <a ui-sref="main.tabs" class="item" ng-click="toggleMenu()">Tabs</a>
                </ul>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu>

    </ion-side-menus>


</script>


<script id="home.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view title="{{navTitle}}" left-buttons="leftButtons">

        <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">

            <h1>Home Page!</h1>

            <a ui-sref="main.info" class="button button-positive">Info</a>

        </ion-content>

    </ion-view>

</script>

<script id="info.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view title="{{navTitle}}" left-buttons="leftButtons">

        <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">

            <h1>Info Page!</h1>

        </ion-content>

    </ion-view>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('entry', {
                url : '/entry',
                templateUrl : 'entry.html',
                controller : 'EntryPageController'
            })

            .state('main', {
                url : '/main',
                templateUrl : 'mainContainer.html',
                abstract : true,
                controller : 'MainController'
            })

            .state('main.home', {
                url: '/home',
                views: {
                    'main': {
                        templateUrl: 'home.html',
                        controller : 'HomePageController'
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('main.info', {
                url: '/info',
                views: {
                    'main': {
                        templateUrl: 'info.html',
                        controller : 'InfoPageController'
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('main.tabs', {
                 url: '/tabs',
                 views: {
                     'main': {
                         templateUrl: 'tabs.html',
                         controller : 'TabsPageController'
                     }
                 }
            })

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/entry');
    }])

    .controller('MainController', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.toggleMenu = function() {
            $scope.sideMenuController.toggleLeft();
        }
    }])

    .controller('EntryPageController', [ '$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
        $scope.navTitle = 'Entry Page';

        $scope.signIn = function() {
            $state.go('main.home');
        }
    }])

    .controller('HomePageController', [ '$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
        $scope.navTitle = 'Home Page';

        $scope.leftButtons = [{
            type: 'button-icon icon ion-navicon',
            tap: function(e) {
                $scope.toggleMenu();
            }
        }];
    }])

    .controller('InfoPageController', [ '$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
        $scope.navTitle = 'Info Page';

        $scope.leftButtons = [{
            type: 'button-icon icon ion-navicon',
            tap: function(e) {
                $scope.toggleMenu();
            }
        }];
    }])

    .controller('TabsPageController', [ '$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
        $scope.navTitle = 'Tab Page';

        $scope.leftButtons = [{
            type: 'button-icon icon ion-navicon',
            tap: function(e) {
                $scope.toggleMenu();
            }
        }];
    }])
```

I have search and tried many different things but I can't seem to figure out how to add a modal to one of the pages. I can do it in a simpler app with only one type of navigation, but this codepen has two types of navigation (side menu and tabs on certian pages) and the controllers are split differently then I am used to and I don't know where to initialize the $ionicModal. I have tried putting in the main controller as well as the home page controller, but if I do, then I get a blank page. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Sorry if I am doing this wrong. I usually don't come on here often.

Comment: may i know which page want modal window?

Comment: @prabhu for this example I guess the home page but really I just don't understand where to put the modal controller, the home page controller, its parent the main controller, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

You should post your attempt that didn't work.  Then I could help more.  However, my wild guess is that the template path you specified is not correct.

Also, please don't post so much code.  Most of this is irrelevant to the issue.  If you want someone to take time to help, then take time to ask concisely.

Here is a working modal example: http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/AHIuh/

```
    // Load the modal from the given template URL
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('modal.html', function($ionicModal) {
    $scope.modal = $ionicModal;
}, {
    // Use our scope for the scope of the modal to keep it simple
    scope: $scope,
    // The animation we want to use for the modal entrance
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
});
```

});

and then on your button (or whatever opens the modal)

`ng-click="modal.show()"`